# Python function to determine if a 'str' object is either 'int' or 'double'

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been asked to define a function to return a string specifying data type ('str', 'int' or 'double') of a string object.
Simply, this function should determine if the input string is actually either an integer (then return a string specifying that it is an integer) or a float (then return a string specifying that it is indeed a floating point number) or if it's just a string, well obviously return 'str'.

I wrote the following, but it's not the desired function:

```
def input_type(value):
    if value.isdigit():
        return'integer'
    elif value.isdigit() == 0:
        try:
            y = float(value)
            return 'double'
        except ValueError:
            return 'string'
```

Comment: What does that mean, "is not the desired function"?

Comment: Maybe check out this link - isinstance is a built in function that may help you with that? https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-type-isinstance/

Comment: For starters, you can replace that `elif ...:` with just `else:`.

Answer (score 1):

something like the below

```
def input_type(value:str):
    if not isinstance(value,str) :
        raise ValueError('input must be a string')
    try:
        int(value)
        return int,value
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(value)
            return float, value
        except ValueError:
            return str,value

print(input_type('jack'))
print(input_type('7'))
print(input_type('7.19'))
try:
    print(input_type({}))
except ValueError:
    print('ValueError raised')
```

output

```
(<class 'str'>, 'jack')
(<class 'int'>, '7')
(<class 'float'>, '7.19')
ValueError raised
```